# Azure File Storage API access using Shared Access Signature

Tags: azure-storage, dynamics-business-central

I'm currently trying to access files & directories on an Azure Storage Account Fileshare (let's call it *rootdirectory* ) from a Dynamics Business Central page action.

The method to access files stored in it is to build and send an HTTP GET request (with a client) to https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/rootdirectory to retrieve a filelist.

I'm trying to use a Shared Access Signature to authenticate the request.

The blocking point that I can't get through is the following error message :

```
Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.
```

I'm setting my request headers like this :

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders().Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders().Add('x-msdate', '2019-02-20');
client.DefaultRequestHeaders().Add('Authorization', '...');
```

My main problem is that I can't seem to find the proper format (to use in the '...' part) asked in the error message **in any tutorial**.

I've tried the following formats (and minor variations inside it)

```
'SharedAccessSignature myaccount:signature'
'SharedAccessSignature sv=2018-03-28&ss=f&srt=sco&sp=rwdlc&se=2019-02-20T18:12:27Z&st=2019-02-20T10:12:27Z&spr=https&sig=signature'
'SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.file.core.windows.net%2Fmyfileshare%2Frootdirectory&sig=signature&se=2019-02-21T22:36:05Z&skn=key1'
```

I also tried putting it in the service URI, nothing better.

Has anyone already encountered this issue ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Was the below response helpful to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend checking the following [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275560/azure-file-share-rest-api-for-xamarin).
They ended up using the below code:

```
public AzureSASToken GetSASFromShare(string shareName)
        {
            var share = _fileclient.GetShareReference(shareName);
            share.CreateIfNotExists();
            string policyName = "UPARSharePolicy";

            // Create a new shared access policy and define its constraints.
            var sharedPolicy = new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
            {
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(15),
                Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read | SharedAccessFilePermissions.Write
            };

            // Get existing permissions for the share.
            var permissions = share.GetPermissions();

            // Add the shared access policy to the share's policies. 
            // Note that each policy must have a unique name.
            // Maximum 5 policies for each share!
            if (!permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Keys.Contains(policyName))
            {
                if (permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Count > 4)
                {
                    var lastAddedPolicyName = permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Keys.Last();
                    permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Remove(lastAddedPolicyName);
                }
                permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add(policyName, sharedPolicy);
                share.SetPermissions(permissions);
            }            

            var sasToken = share.GetSharedAccessSignature(sharedPolicy);
            //fileSasUri = new Uri(share.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + sasToken);
            return new AzureSASToken ()
            {
               Name = shareName,
               Url = share.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + "/",
               SASToken = sasToken        
            };
        }
```