# Authorization request header for Azure Create File REST API when using Shared Access Signatures

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to use the Azure File Service REST API to create a file from PowerShell, using a Shared Access Signature, and I can't figure out how to set the required `Authorization` header when the authorization scheme is Shared Access Signature.

I'm only using PowerShell to try and figure out the REST API syntax, then I need to port the REST calls to JavaScript so they can be called client side.

Here's what I've discovered so far:

1.The MSDN documentation for `Create File` states that the header is required, but the sample request only illustrates `SharedKey` authorization header.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file#request

2.The Shared Access Signature examples work fine for generating a SAS, but they don't document request headers at all in the example following calls that use the SAS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples#file-examples

3.There's a nice Xamarin answer here, but the answer only explicitly sets the `x-ms-type` and `x-ms-content-length` headers, the rest seem to part of a call to `client.DefaultRequestHeaders`.
[Azure File Share REST API for Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275560/azure-file-share-rest-api-for-xamarin)

My code at the moment looks as follows:

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "mystorage" -StorageAccountKey "REDACTED"
$start = Get-Date
$end = $start.AddHours(2.0)
$uri = New-AzStorageFileSASToken -ShareName "web" -Path "documents/newfile.txt" -Permission "w" -StartTime $start -EndTime $end -Context $ctx -FullUri
$headers = @{'x-ms-version' = '2019-12-12'; 'x-ms-type' = 'file'; 'x-ms-content-length' = '55'; 'x-ms-date' = 'Thu, 22 Oct 2020 19:28:55 BST'}
invoke-restmethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -InFile $file -Headers $headers
```

The result of the final call is:

```
invoke-restmethod : InvalidHeaderValueThe value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
```

My question is, does anyone have a valid example of the complete HTTP request including headers when calling the Azure File Service REST API?

Comment: What happens if you start with `$headers = @{'x-ms-version' = '2019-12-12'}` and add one at a time?

Comment: @CasperDijkstra - great question. I added things back in one at a time, and it seems like the problem was with my date formatting:  
`$headers = @{'x-ms-version' = '2018-11-09'; 'x-ms-type' = 'file'; 'x-ms-content-length' = '1024'; 'x-ms-date' = (Get-Date).tostring('R')}` works fine. Note I was still getting error messages about HTTP headers being missing, so I went back to an earlier version of Azure Storage API (2018-11-09). It seems like quite a few additional headers became mandatory after version 2019-02-02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a complete HTTP request directly from the Azure portal:

Go to Azure portal>Storage accounts>your accounts>Shared access signature, find **Allowed services** and select **File**, then click **generate SAS and connection string** to generate **File service SAS URL**,it is actually composed of **Connection string+SAS token**.

[image]

Use of **Shared access signature** does not require **authorization header** because it is already included in the request information.

[image]

Comment: This is helpful in terms of allowing someone to compare their PowerShell generated SAS URL against one generated by the Azure Portal, but the Portal screen above doesn't shed any light as to which headers are needed. This answer is also helpful in clarifying that the Authorization header is *not* needed - despite what the MSDN page in my first link says. Nevertheless, it seems there a list of HTTP headers that *are* needed alongside the file service SAS URL, since it definitely doesn't work if called without any headers.

Comment: Actually I think you *have* answered the question. No authorization header is needed, which is title of post. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben It would really help if you could add a list of the headers that are actually needed when using SAS. I came here with the exact problem you described. I have the correct SAS but I still get the error when I omit the Authorization header.

Comment: @Gichamba - see my comment above - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64488711/authorization-request-header-for-azure-create-file-rest-api-when-using-shared-ac/64495170?noredirect=1#comment114051976_64488711. I never got it working with the x-ms-version=2019-12-12, only with the older x-ms-version=2018-11-09. The x-ms-version header will determine what other headers are needed, as far as I can tell.